# SQL to read XML from file into PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, xml

How can I write SQL to read an XML file into a PostgreSQL `XML` value?

PostgreSQL has a native [XML data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-xml.html) with the `XMLPARSE` function to parse  a text string to that type. It also has ways to read data from the filesystem; the `COPY` statement, among others.

But I don't see a way to write native PostgreSQL SQL statements to read the content from a filesystem entry and use that to populate an `XML` value. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **[`pg_read_binary_file`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-admin.html) function** can do this.

It has limitations: new in PostgreSQL 9.1 or above; must be a session owned by database superuser; must read a file within the database directory or below. Those are acceptable in my use case.

So the following will work to create a native `XML` value from a file:

```sql
-- PostgreSQL 9.1 or later.
SELECT
    XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT convert_from(
        pg_read_binary_file('foo.xml'), 'UTF8'));
```

In PostgreSQL 8.3 – 9.0, the [`pg_read_file`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-admin.html) function can be used, with the additional limitation that you can't specify a file-specific encoding (it reads the file as text in the current session's encoding).

```sql
-- PostgreSQL earlier than 9.1.
SELECT
    XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT pg_read_file('foo.xml'));
```

Comment: note that the above solution requires your server was compiled `--with-libxml`

Answer (score 10):

Similar to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/how-to-insert-file-data-into-a-postgresql-bytea-column/2962#2962) answer to a previous question, and if you don't want [the restrictions of `pg_read_file()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE) (in short: `pg_read_file` can't read files outside the database directory, and reads text in the current session's character encoding).

This function works for any path, but needs to be created as superuser:

```
create or replace function stack.bytea_import(p_path text, p_result out bytea) 
                   language plpgsql as $$
declare
  l_oid oid;
begin
  select lo_import(p_path) into l_oid;
  select lo_get(l_oid) INTO p_result;
  perform lo_unlink(l_oid);
end;$$;
```

[`lo_get`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/lo-funcs.html) was introduced in 9.4 so for older versions you would need:

```
create or replace function stack.bytea_import(p_path text, p_result out bytea) 
                   language plpgsql as $$
declare
  l_oid oid;
  r record;
begin
  p_result := '';
  select lo_import(p_path) into l_oid;
  for r in ( select data 
             from pg_largeobject 
             where loid = l_oid 
             order by pageno ) loop
    p_result = p_result || r.data;
  end loop;
  perform lo_unlink(l_oid);
end;$$;
```

then:

```
select convert_from(stack.bytea_import('/tmp/test.xml'), 'utf8')::xml;
```

Comment: +1, thanks for pointing out that there are limits to the file-reading functions.

Comment: +1 nice trick to circumvent `pg_read_file()`. The same can also be achieved with a temporary table and `COPY` - populate only 1 column of 1 row.

Answer (score 3):

I have posted a complete implementation of what you are asking for in a [recent answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491479/xml-data-to-postgresql-database/7628453#7628453).

The key features are the `xpath()` function, `pg_read_file()`, array handling, plpgsql functions, ..

Comment: Rather different (and more heavyweight) than what I need in this case. But +1 for the good direction, thank you.

Comment: It's not *that* heavyweight, my example is just very complete with redundant elements to demonstrate syntax variants.