# How to select bytea data as binary data, inserted as hex-encoded from binary

Tags: postgresql

The post [How to insert (file) data into a PostgreSQL bytea column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/how-to-insert-file-data-into-a-postgresql-bytea-column) was helpful.

However, when I select these columns, I get the same hex encoded data.

For instance:

```
> select substring(smallblob,0,64) from longdata where blobi d=1;
\xd0cf11e0a1b11ae1000000000000000000000000000000003b000300feff09000600000000000 00000000000010000006a0000000000000000100000670000 
(1 row)
```

How can I `SELECT` this data in binary format?  `CAST' and`CONVERT` do not appear to support a 'binary' option.

Comment: why do you want binary data on your screen? it will include all sorts of nasty surprises if you do...

Answer (score 3):

You're not going to get binary data out of `psql` and `SELECT`. `psql` will format it for readability.  You could try something with `lo_export` similar to the answer in [How to insert (file) data into a PostgreSQL bytea column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/how-to-insert-file-data-into-a-postgresql-bytea-column) to get the data written to a file.

However, most PostgreSQL client adapters (perl DBI, Ruby 'pg', etc) can give you the data in binary when you `SELECT` bytea columns.  Just write a little program using an appropriate adapter in the language of your choice.