# How to insert very big XML data file to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, import, xml, plpgsql, blob

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5 and trying to import XML data file to database.
To load the XML I use this function from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/how-to-insert-file-data-into-a-postgresql-bytea-column)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bytea_import(p_path text, p_result out bytea) as
$$
DECLARE 
  l_oid oid;
BEGIN 
  SELECT lo_import(p_path) INTO l_oid;
  SELECT lo_get(l_oid) INTO p_result;
  PERFORM lo_unlink(l_oid);
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I successfully load data from a small XML file, but when I try a 4GB XML file,
it returns error:

```
SQL Error [54000]: ERROR: large object read request is too large  
Where: SQL statement "SELECT lo_get(l_oid)" PL/pgSQL function
bytea_import(text) line 6 at SQL statement.
```

It seems lo_get cannot read/extract very large data.
It's said that since version 9.4, PostgreSQL can handle up to 4TB, so how can I import very large XML data file to PostgreSQL 9.5?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `lo_import` is successful, creating a 4GB large object.

But the hard limit for the `bytea` datatype is 1GB, so these contents are not transferable into a bytea.